# cookies.txt not working on Httrack version 3.49-2

Tags: curl, cookies, httrack

hi guys I'm using httrack and using cookies for the authentication but it seems my cookie doesnt work the syntax i'm using

```
httrack -b1 -%M -r1 −F "Mozilla/4.5 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"  https://koran.tempo.co/read/446927/kpk-genjot-operasi-penangkapan-di-masa-transisi  -O "./tempo"
```

and the cookies i'm using is like this and its generated by chrome extension

```
# HTTP Cookie File downloaded with cookies.txt by Genuinous @genuinous
# This file can be used by wget, curl, aria2c and other standard compliant tools.
# Usage Examples:
#   1) wget -x --load-cookies cookies.txt "https://koran.tempo.co/read/446927/kpk-genjot-operasi-penangkapan-di-masa-transisi"
#   2) curl --cookie cookies.txt "https://koran.tempo.co/read/446927/kpk-genjot-operasi-penangkapan-di-masa-transisi"
#   3) aria2c --load-cookies cookies.txt "https://koran.tempo.co/read/446927/kpk-genjot-operasi-penangkapan-di-masa-transisi"
#
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1603453020  __auc   98936e9b16bb60a3155e173a44c
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1634902620  _ga GA1.2.575044688.1562127250
bisnis.tempo.co FALSE   /   FALSE   1581667863  _ants_utm_v2    eyJzb3VyY2UiOiJnb29nbGUuY29tIiwibWVkaXVtIjoicmVmZXJyZXIiLCJjYW1wYWlnbiI6IiIs%0D%0AImNvbnRlbnQiOiIiLCJ0ZXJtIjoiIiwidHlwZSI6InJlZmVycmVyIiwidGltZSI6MTU2NjExNTg2%0D%0AMzU2NCwiY2hlY2tzdW0iOiJaMjl2WjJ4bExtTnZiUzF5WldabGNuSmxjaTB0TVRVMk5qRXhOVGcy%0D%0ATXpVMk5BPT0ifQ%3D%3D
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1597651863  _ym_uid 1566115864775904393
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1597651863  _ym_d   1566115864
bisnis.tempo.co FALSE   /   FALSE   1634455176  ai_client_id    11269073000.1566115864
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1629187863  au_aid  11269073000
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1629187863  au_gt   1566115864116
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1634717787  _ants_services  %5B%22dfp%22%2C%22cuid%22%5D
.bisnis.tempo.co    TRUE    /   FALSE   1634455889  dable_uid   79179164.1560965184973
.metro.tempo.co TRUE    /   FALSE   1632730466  dable_uid   79179164.1560965184973
metro.tempo.co  FALSE   /   FALSE   1632730467  ai_client_id    11269073000.1569657321
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   9345657317  OB-USER-TOKEN   b57b255a-24ee-479a-9ba7-00adf62ae1e4
nasional.tempo.co   FALSE   /   FALSE   1632730416  ai_client_id    11269073000.1569657677
.nasional.tempo.co  TRUE    /   FALSE   1632730402  dable_uid   79179164.1560965184973
metro.tempo.co  FALSE   /   FALSE   1585210466  _ants_utm_v2    eyJzb3VyY2UiOiJmYWNlYm9vay5jb20iLCJtZWRpdW0iOiJyZWZlcnJlciIsImNhbXBhaWduIjoi%0D%0AIiwiY29udGVudCI6IiIsInRlcm0iOiIiLCJ0eXBlIjoicmVmZXJyZXIiLCJ0aW1lIjoxNTY5NjU4%0D%0ANDY2MzEyLCJjaGVja3N1bSI6IlptRmpaV0p2YjJzdVkyOXRMWEpsWm1WeWNtVnlMUzB4TlRZNU5q%0D%0AVTRORFkyTXpFeSJ9
langganan.tempo.co  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   bgbahg57bqqj2897os9o942vs6
.langganan.tempo.co TRUE    /   FALSE   253402257600    G_ENABLED_IDPS  google
majalah.tempo.co    FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   b8q0af77qvkbfv8i85h8tdldm3
.tempo.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   1602830715  __cfduid    d39c872b00bf886eb3b9ebcd0d013fbdb1571294717
.tempo.com  TRUE    /   TRUE    1573886719  meteored_last   1
.tempo.com  TRUE    /   TRUE    1602830720  meteored    us1-2c9bdc2f85f1b3459040a15b51ffdd58764d652a6634d0a84ca9a798c90cbeb8
.tempo.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   1634366720  _ga GA1.2.334570289.1571294720
.tempo.com  TRUE    /   TRUE    1602917120  meteored_gdpr   0
.tempo.com  TRUE    /   TRUE    1573886730  meteored_gps    1
.majalah.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   253402257600    G_ENABLED_IDPS  google
.majalah.tempo.co   TRUE    /   TRUE    1602928760  fbm_332404380172618 base_domain=.majalah.tempo.co
www.tempo.co    FALSE   /   FALSE   1634717787  ai_client_id    11269073000.1571366041
.www.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1634717790  dable_uid   79179164.1560965184973
koran.tempo.co  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   vrj2u9fvmrpt0mn1qeh6dqvn16
www.tempo.co    FALSE   /   FALSE   1586922957  _ants_utm_v2    eyJzb3VyY2UiOiJnb29nbGUuY29tIiwibWVkaXVtIjoicmVmZXJyZXIiLCJjYW1wYWlnbiI6IiIs%0D%0AImNvbnRlbnQiOiIiLCJ0ZXJtIjoiIiwidHlwZSI6InJlZmVycmVyIiwidGltZSI6MTU3MTM3MDk1%0D%0ANzU1MCwiY2hlY2tzdW0iOiJaMjl2WjJ4bExtTnZiUzF5WldabGNuSmxjaTB0TVRVM01UTTNNRGsx%0D%0ATnpVMU1BPT0ifQ%3D%3D
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571976530  FA  0
.gaya.tempo.co  TRUE    /   FALSE   1634443809  dable_uid   79179164.1560965184973
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571976623  ivx_1082514 5
cantik.tempo.co FALSE   /   FALSE   1634444046  ai_client_id    11269073000.1571372046
.cantik.tempo.co    TRUE    /   FALSE   1634444047  dable_uid   79179164.1560965184973
.dunia.tempo.co TRUE    /   FALSE   1634456611  dable_uid   79179164.1560965184973
dunia.tempo.co  FALSE   /   FALSE   1634456625  ai_client_id    11269073000.1571372050
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571976858  ivx_944363  5
.koran.tempo.co TRUE    /   FALSE   253402257600    G_ENABLED_IDPS  google
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571986555  ivx_1066183 25
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571987217  ivx_1083197 75
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571987259  ivx_1083154 40
seleb.tempo.co  FALSE   /   FALSE   1634454821  ai_client_id    11269073000.1571382821
.seleb.tempo.co TRUE    /   FALSE   1634454821  dable_uid   79179164.1560965184973
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571987724  ivx_1083155 100
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571987924  ivx_1083266 75
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571987972  ivx_1083232 45
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571988129  ivx_1068176 150
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571988328  ivx_1075470 195
sport.tempo.co  FALSE   /   FALSE   1634455531  ai_client_id    11269073000.1571383531
.sport.tempo.co TRUE    /   FALSE   1634455531  dable_uid   79179164.1560965184973
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571988521  ivx_999550  95
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571988588  ivx_1065297 65
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571988980  ivx_1073522 135
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571989170  ivx_875599  110
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571989326  ivx_1078581 60
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571989408  ivx_1083265 75
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571989493  ivx_908581  80
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571989588  ivx_1080417 90
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571989620  ivx_1083366 30
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571917020  _gid    GA1.2.1094969857.1571622173
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1587396135  _pk_ref.580248650.54bf  %5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C1571628136%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%22%5D
.tekno.tempo.co TRUE    /   FALSE   1634701161  dable_uid   79179164.1560965184973
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1572233972  ivx_976170  10
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1634713689  ai.audience %7B%22audiences%22%3A%22%5B%5D%22%2C%22time%22%3A1571641689326%7D
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1600071064  _pk_id.580248650.54bf   7cb4ec8ff922a660.1566115864.8.1571645787.1571628136.
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1634717787  an_session  zrzgzkzmzkzqzgzjznzdzizizhzlzqzjzkzgzjzjzjzdzizmzkzizlznzmzjzizmzdzgzdzizmzkzizlznzmzkzrzkzdzizmzkzizlznzmzkzrzkzdzjzdzizjzqzdzizizd2421zdzjzdzhzlziznzn
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1634717787  dgs 1571645787%3A3%3A0
.langganan.tempo.co TRUE    /   TRUE    1603271489  fbm_332404380172618 base_domain=.langganan.tempo.co
magz.tempo.co   FALSE   /   FALSE   1572253950  AWSALB  LRxx4aZb2glYf8mmWsQYW+rpANXzjsp6mC7eGDf4tQbIw/SM1C4Oz7wJlWjlWJZL2AlULlZkjPs36/PutPeOZRIIt9kXcNO/UjgXBk7pGBe8ezRwuJ4eLNUfY8mC
langganan.tempo.co  FALSE   /   FALSE   1572253964  AWSALB  gh8lJffttKf+0zJjzceZDDoApjVpvrMAE42TwTKBxhXWtSFDDqEkmCZY0HJQJ6IbY6AchVz4xOQ0RMWxxuAxIxI9pjBHsUXJu+yu1JSqgWfdvwm5uv8gUudW5WXr
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1572145287  notifLogin  true
majalah.tempo.co    FALSE   /   FALSE   1572338522  AWSALB  YxD1DiG7cPPemD39Ya+KGJdQd+Cy8y3gaJ2LhfxZ7hLSwRQFGH9xrzEmZlmL4t08Gu0x9DCWpQwwas6oL+HRstLvGaQ0QtlvMYj3gUMlNPiSbvTge9xBgKOVOptO
images-tm.tempo.co  FALSE   /   FALSE   1572431669  AWSALB  uQqgxYymGOWgZYw724hSr3ir3tVSLfAHrTI67PhDr3NvPtFMS6DB5qu/dTbZU7tNmr6j5XdwNRsnVnnG2d2GfI9ZdmC4kmNH1dGQLuDTeCHUpfvsb8dtgGkqCGB1
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571832420  __asc   96757d6e16df85b48287f6b09d2
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571830674  _gat_UA-23817453-1  1
.koran.tempo.co TRUE    /   TRUE    1603453018  fbm_332404380172618 base_domain=.koran.tempo.co
.koran.tempo.co TRUE    /   TRUE    1571835600  fbsr_332404380172618    hm1amlFKvqMog7GYHwnpFPf4jUwS6B8omJGNvzBHQug.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
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571834220  user    a%3A24%3A%7Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22569019%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22no_pelanggan%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%221571647004%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22email%22%3Bs%3A16%3A%22danial%40nubela.co%22%3Bs%3A15%3A%22langganan_start%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%222019-10-21%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22langganan_end%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%222020-01-21%22%3Bs%3A16%3A%22status_langganan%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A15%3A%22paket_langganan%22%3BN%3Bs%3A21%3A%22name_status_langganan%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22Berlangganan%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22paket%22%3BN%3Bs%3A10%3A%22nama_depan%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22DanialHabibi%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22photo%22%3BN%3Bs%3A5%3A%22valid%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%220%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22paket_kt%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A24%3A%22name_status_langganan_kt%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22Berlangganan%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22start_date_kt%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%222019-10-21%22%3Bs%3A11%3A%22end_date_kt%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%222020-01-21%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22paket_mbm%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%220%22%3Bs%3A25%3A%22name_status_langganan_mbm%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22Belum+Berlangganan%22%3Bs%3A14%3A%22start_date_mbm%22%3BN%3Bs%3A12%3A%22end_date_mbm%22%3BN%3Bs%3A8%3A%22paket_te%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%220%22%3Bs%3A24%3A%22name_status_langganan_te%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22Belum+Berlangganan%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22start_date_te%22%3BN%3Bs%3A11%3A%22end_date_te%22%3BN%3B%7D
.tempo.co   TRUE    /   FALSE   1571834220  freeArtikel 5
koran.tempo.co  FALSE   /   FALSE   1572435419  AWSALB  rwfi3WEn6Fj9qNZN9G+h95n88pZASDx4kUd8inGB1AtUb8ufhS2smlROV44nhCZPkoUCiRWdGHwp+2KbHWtv/sb+bWUnqsjYxYboGyuGLfDXLMxAYHimJSnAG6rX
```

but when i'm using this cookies using curl its normally working any idea why?? did i miss something on the httrack parameter/options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried much with the windows version to get cookies.txt working with my site but could not, i just added it as a header instead and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem, could not get cookies.txt file to be recognised on WinHttrack, switched over to a Mac (homebrew) version and it all worked fine!
(also, the chrome extension I used for getting the cookies was this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-cookiestxt/bgaddhkoddajcdgocldbbfleckgcbcid )